# How to establish zmq connections between docker containers using docker compose option network_mode: host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to establish a connection using the draft server/client pattern of ZeroMQ across different docker containers. For that, I have a `zmq.server` that is running in `docker_container_server`. In addition, I have a `zmq.client` which runs in `docker_container_client`. Both containers are based on different docker images. Despite using the `network_mode: host` option with docker compose, this does not work. If I do the same within one container, it just works fine.

The docker-compose files are the following.
docker-compose-client.yaml:

```
services:
  client:
    privileged: true
    image: client-image
    container_name: client
    command: tail -F anything
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - "ROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311"
      - "ROS_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1"
    build:
      context: ./client
      network: host
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

docker-compose-server.yaml:

```
services:
  server:
    image: server-image
    privileged: true
    container_name: server
    network_mode: host
    command: tail -F anything
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.server
```

The server application uses pyzmq as follows:

```
import zmq

class ServerExample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.url = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'
        self.server = self.ctx.socket(zmq.SERVER)
        self.server.bind(self.url)
        try:
            while not self.stop:
                msg = self.server.recv(copy=False) # stucks in this line
                print(msg.routing_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ServerExample()
```

The client uses cppzmq as follows: (I also tried a pyzmq-client. This also works within a container but not across different containers.)

```
#include <zmq.hpp>

class ClientExample
{
private:
    zmq::socket_t socket;
    zmq::context_t ctx;
 public:
     ClientExample() 
     {
        socket = zmq::socket_t(ctx, zmq::socket_type::client);
        socket_.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
        char[] some_data;
        socket_.send(zmq::buffer(some_data)); // not received by server                
     }
};
```

The containers are started by `docker compose up server` and `docker compose up client`.

When I do everything in one container and have a look on `netstat -t | grep 5555`, I get the same result in the container and on the host: (In this case, there are two clients and one server)

```
tcp        0   2856 localhost:56674         localhost:5555          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0   2856 localhost:5555          localhost:47666         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:5555          localhost:56674         ESTABLISHED
```

That is why I think that the docker compose option `network_mode: host` is properly working in my case.

When I start the `docker_container_server` and `docker_container_client`, the execution stucks in the line where the server should receive a message. `netstat -t | grep 5555` ouputs both on the host and in the containers just nothing.

The versions I use:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker Compose version v2.12.2
- Docker Engine Version 20.10.21
- libzmq v4.3.4
- cppzmq v4.9.0
- pyzmq v25.0.0b1

I searched a lot through the internet, read the documentations of docker, docker compose, zmq etc. I came to the conclusion, that it should work with the `network_mode: host` option and I think I confirmed that the `network_mode: host` option works as it should. The code itself should not contain any mistakes, as it works fine within one container. But I didn't figure out, why the communication doesn't work across containers.

Comment: Since you're using a TCP transport for ZeroMQ, normal Docker networking should work fine (see, for example, [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation).  What is leading you to disable the networking layer with `network_mode: host`?  The `entrypoint:` overrides keep the main container processes from running at all; if you delete this, does the server start?  What's the actual problem you're running into?

Comment: I start the server and client(s) via command line. I doublechecked how far the execution goes. The server stucks in the line where the first message should be received from the client. The client doesn’t stop within the code I cited. Later, when I try to receive something from the server, it also stucks. But this is because the server didn’t send anything as it still waits in the ‘‘‘recv’’’ function to receive the first message from the client. So the applications are running, the server app just waits at the line ‘’’msg = self.server.recv(copy=False)’’’ forever.

Comment: The reason I came up with disabling the networking layer is that I read the networking is faster if the layer is disabled. I think that may be relevant as I have quite a few messages to exchange. Now, as it doesn’t work, I may switch to using the networking layer. But I still want to understand why it doesn’t work as expected.